# Laravel. Каким инструментом воспользоваться, чтобы однократно и контролируемо изменять данные в БД

Tags: laravel

Я новичок в мире Laravel, поэтому, такой вопрос.

Есть такое понятие, как миграции. Когда я работаю с YII, то запросто в миграциях не только меняю структуру БД, но и произвожу манипуляции с данными - изменяю, добавляю, делаю импорт из других источников. Очень удобно: файл процесса изменения данных находится под управлением GIT, есть возможность накатить и откатить изменения. Отработанная миграция уходит в историю, нет шанса запустить ее еще раз, случайно.

При переходе в Laravel задумываюсь о применении такой же практики, но во всех источниках вижу, что такой подход не приветствуется в мире Laravel. Мол, миграции - это для управления структурой БД, и всё.

Seeders? Насколько я понял, это для однократного заполнения базы при старте проекта. Больше не вижу им нормального применения.

А как вы делаете в Laravel типичные вещи по изменению содержимого базы данных?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть готовый пакет: [timokoerber/laravel-one-time-operations](https://packagist.org/packages/timokoerber/laravel-one-time-operations).

Их слоган:

> Запускайте операции один раз после развертывания — так же, как вы делаете это с миграциями!

Получается и технологично, и управляемо, и не нарушает структуру.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду изучать!

Comment: Это, пожалуй, ближе всего к ожидаемому функционалу.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения ответственности и чистоты кода это правильный подход. У вас миграции отвечают за структуру, а сидинги за наполнение. И никак иначе. Это легче поддерживать и легче тестировать.

Что касается того, как изменять бд на проде. По факту мы следим что добавилось и выполняем команду посева данных через `--class=....`, то есть выполняем конкретный сидинг. Если попробовать выполнить просто db:seed ларавель выкинет предупреждение, что Вы пытаетесь выполнить сидинги на проде и можете потерять все боевые данные.

Что можно сделать. (не искал готовых решений в интернете, есть своё домашнее). Мы делаем свой сервис посева данных который будет иметь такую же структуру как и таблица migrations. И данный сервис будет выполнять только те сидинги которые не были выполнены. Делается своя команда db:production-seed и она будет выполнять только последние файлы загруженные на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Через --class  - нет гарантии, что кто-то (я, завтра, случайно), не запустит этот seed повторно. Зная себя :), не решусь.

Свое решение - да, как вариант на крайний случай.